# How can I edit the color of a DisclosurePanel header

Tags: html, css, gwt

I'm using GWT to present Disclosure Panels on my web page. I've succesfully created and presented the panel, but the colour of the header is blue. It's the typical link's colour. I've found the function getHeaderTextAccessor() but this can only edit the text and not the style of the header.How can I change the colour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to your "public" folder and in there create a style.css file and add

```
.myDisclosurePanel {
    background-color: #000000
 }
```

and then in the same "public" folder add the line

```
<link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"">
```

in the  section. Then in your code apply the style "myDisclosurePanel" to disclosure panel object

```
.setStyleName("myDisclosurePanel");
```

Answer (score 0):

If GWT means Google Webkit Toolkit (and I'm not familiar with either terminology), then according to this [link](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DisclosurePanel.html), just use one of those css rules. It should change the color, hopefully.

```
.gwt-DisclosurePanel { the panel's primary style }
.gwt-DisclosurePanel-open { dependent style set when panel is open }
.gwt-DisclosurePanel-closed { dependent style set when panel is closed }
.header { the header section }
.content { the content section }
```

(from link above)

Comment: Yes. it stands for Google Web Toolkit.Thank you. However I still don't understand where to place these css lines. I mean should I place them inside my html page or can I use them to set the style from my Java code?

Comment: css usually go in the <style> block within your HTML file. OR you can create a new stylesheet , place the css styles inside it and link the stylesheet with your Html file.

Comment: If you have a separate stylesheet, then you place it there.  But it doesn't sound like you do. Here's a simpler way to place it in your html page. Put <style type="text/css"> .gwt-DisclosurePanel h1{color:red} </style>  Put it in head. Also, I just randomly used h1 element since you said header but change it to whatever element you're talking about. Does this make sense?

Comment: In the default GWT project it uses the default GWT css file which gets used by default. You must create a .css file and place it in the same folder as your .html  entry point. Use that style sheet inside your HTML. Then in your code set the style name on disclosure panel like  .setStyleName("your_css_class");  and that should do it.